# Displaying an uploaded image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: geotiff-tiff, google-earth-engine

I have been trying to view an uploaded image on google earth engine, but I am not able to tell what's the problem with the code, as I didn't see any error or layer on the base map after running the code.

```
var image = ee.Image("users/chandrakant/RZSC_2000_2015_Trial_2");
var vizParams = {
  bands: ['b1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1000.0,
  palette: ['bbe029', '0a9501', '074b03'],
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
//Map.addLayer(image, vizParams, 'Rootzone Storage Capacity');
Map.centerObject(image);

print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', image.projection());
var reprojected = image.reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 500);
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', reprojected.projection());
Map.addLayer(reprojected, vizParams, 'Reprojected');
```

I have tried several things, even tried to reproject the image, but nothing seems to work at all.

The tiff image is shared in the link below.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hpqj2tfei8o82xo/AADNPWEA4PN9ybNN6zx8771Ca?dl=0

The image properties show my band to be masked, I don't know why.

```
Pixels
Reprojected: Image (1 band)
b1: masked              \\Masked, why??
Objects
Reprojected: Image (1 band)
type: Image
bands: List (1 element)
0: "b1", float, EPSG:4326, 1x1 px
id: b1
crs: EPSG:4326
crs_transform: List (6 elements)
data_type: float
dimensions: [1,1]
origin: [19369,20037]
0: 19369
1: 20037
properties: Object (2 properties)
system:footprint: LinearRing, 5 vertices
system:index: 0
```